# Read multiple Json in one file in Spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read in spark a json file that have a json file per line

```
["io", {"in": 8, "out": 0, "dev": "68", "time": 1532035082.614868}]
["io", {"in": 0, "out": 0, "dev": "68", "time": 1532035082.97122}]
["test", {"A": [{"para1":[], "para2": true, "para3": 68, "name":"", "observation":[[2,3],[3,2]],"time": 1532035082.97122}]}]
```

It is a bit tricky because each line is a valid json file.
with pandas I do direcly:

```
pd.read_json(filepath,compression='infer', orient='records, lines=True)
```

But in spark with DataFrame it does not work

```
 spark.read.option('multiline','true').json(filepath)
```

I tried to read the file line by line but I still have an error:

```
   lines = sc.textFile(filepath)
   llist = lines.collect()
   for line in llist:
        print(line)
        df = spark.read.option('multiline','true).json(line)
        df.printSchema()
```

the error is IllegalArgumentException:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: .....

thanks for you help to find out a solution

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to read as a text file and parse each row as an array of two strings:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.text(filepath).withColumn(
    'value', 
    F.from_json('value', 'array<string>')
).select(
    F.col('value')[0].alias('c0'), 
    F.col('value')[1].alias('c1')
)

df.show(truncate=False)
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|c0  |c1                                                                                                          |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|io  |{"in":8,"out":0,"dev":"68","time":1.532035082614868E9}                                                      |
|io  |{"in":0,"out":0,"dev":"68","time":1.53203508297122E9}                                                       |
|test|{"A":[{"para1":[],"para2":true,"para3":68,"name":"","observation":[[2,3],[3,2]],"time":1.53203508297122E9}]}|
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But note that column `c1` is of string type. It is not possible for Spark to behave like pandas where the column holds dictionaries with different schemas.

Comment: hi,
what if `F´?
It is not defined